# Matlab: Scale data, to plot multiple vectors on a single graph

Tags: matlab, plot, scale

I want to plot the following, on one single scaled graph. Here is my data and single plots of this data:

```
A = [11 115 167 44 51 5 6];
B = [100 1 1 87];
C = [2000 625];
D = [81 623 45 48 6 14 429 456 94];
E = [89];
F = [44 846 998 2035 498 4 68 4 1 89];

G = {A,B,C,D,E,F};
[max_val, idx] = max(cellfun(@numel, G)); % Find max sizes of vectors

figure(1);plot(1:numel(A),A,'*');
figure(2);plot(1:numel(B),B,'*');
figure(3);plot(1:numel(C),C,'*');
figure(4);plot(1:numel(D),D,'*');
figure(5);plot(1:numel(E),E,'*');
figure(6);plot(1:numel(F),F,'*');
```

How do I use `max_val` to represent 100%, in order to scale my x-axis data into a single graph. The result should be a single graph, with an x-axis of 0 to 100% (Thus the first value in the vector should represent 0%, and the last value in a vector should represent 100%), and y-values are unchanged.

In this case `max_val` is 10, and represents vector `F`. This should thus be the one graph that does not need to be scaled. All other graphs should thus be stretched out(scaled) on the x-axis, to be plotted on the same graph.

---

To explain with pictures, here is a conventional unscaled plot of all the data points on the same graph:

[image]

Here is the approximate result I want, which is a scaled plot of all the data points on the same graph (Achieved with manual excel tampering):

[image]

I hope this is clear.
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still, not 100% sure if I understood, what you want. But if you just want to have your x-Axis for each field in your cell between 0 and 100%, I recommend you the `rescale` function:

```
A = [11 115 167 44 51 5 6];
B = [100 1 1 87];
C = [2000 625];
D = [81 623 45 48 6 14 429 456 94];
E = [89];
F = [44 846 998 2035 498 4 68 4 1 89];
G = {A,B,C,D,E,F};

xScaled = cellfun(@(x) rescale(1:length(x),0,100),G,'UniformOutput',false);

for i = 1:length(G)
    plot(xScaled{i},G{i},'*')
    hold on
end
```